# Beautiful soup - how to extract a string from an object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning Beautiful soup. I have succeeded in tracking down the html lines that I need.
My next step is to extract an Id value from those lines.

The code to find the lines looks like this:

```
object = soup_station.find('img',{'src': re.compile("^Controls")})
```

If I now print object I will get this, for example:

```
<img src="Controls/RiverLevels/ChartImage.jpg?Id=471&amp;ChartType=Histogram" id="StationDetails_Chart1_chartImage" alt="Current river level" />
```

The part I want to extract in the line above is the `"471"` after `Id=`.

I tried using `re.search` on object but it seems that object is not text.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the following:

```
s = '<img src="Controls/RiverLevels/ChartImage.jpg?Id=471&amp;ChartType=Histogram" id="StationDetails_Chart1_chartImage" alt="Current river level" />'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urlparse import urlsplit, parse_qs


soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
# find the node with a src starting with Controls
node = soup.find('img',{'src': re.compile("^Controls")})
# Break up the url in the src attribute
url_split = urlsplit(node['src'])
# Parse out the query parameter from the url
qs = parse_qs(url_split.query)
# Display the value for `Id`
print qs['Id'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you are performing the regex search on the object's source. You can give this a try:

```
import re
ele = soup_station.find('img')
src = ele['src']

match = re.search(r'\?Id=(\d+)', src)
ele_id = match.group(1)
```

Comment: I had a problem with this when find found an object with no src attribute. Wasn't sure how to fix it so I tried the urlsplt answer. But thanks anyway.